# How to let PHP set the evercookie securely

Tags: php, javascript

How to let PHP set the [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) wihtout from within another page .

in another words , i have a page that checks the ever cookie , but i don't want the page to give the cookie value to the user (i don't want the user to see the evercookie value in the page source) , this might be done using some other page that is called by evercookie if there's no cookie value . how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

studied the class , edited it .
now the class checs if cookie has no value , it creates an image object , and fetches it from server , the server creates a string [value][one-way-encrypted-value] and encodes it in a PNG image , the class opens the png image and decodes the image back to a strig and sets the value . 
i hope this would be a pain for any bot to make it .

Answer (score 4):

What you should do is use a value that's unique to a database entry that actually means something, but is nothing more than a randomly generated string to the user. So that when you wanna know what it means, you just check your database for the unique entry and then get the information. Then it doesn't matter what the user sees.

For example, on my sites if a user wishes to remain logged in I set their cookie as a random string (such as 2947927e9suipohdoy20 [it's usually much longer though, like a random number hashed by SHA-512]) and then in their account I have a RememberMe field that stores unique values, I search my database for the string and bam! I have their account!

Comment: database entries would be SLOW for 1M visits a day . a better solution was to send a cookie with [VALUE][ENCRYPTED_VALUE] using a one way encryption algorithm with a key that is stored on the server , then check this key by encrypting the value and check it with the encrypted value , by this way no one would send a cookie that is not created by your server . but still , assuming the user uses a bot , this bot would get that cookie from your html page and send it back anyway . you would be wasting queries and resources ...

Comment: Yes, because everybody gets 1M visits a day.

Comment: Especially someone asking such advanced questions about cookies ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of sending data to the browser such that a user could not retrieve it if they wanted, since that information has to be sent back as part of a HTTP response. HTTP is plain text, and anyone even remotely interested in what you're sending can easily obtain the full response.

Just because (your average) browser doesn't necessarily display some things, doesn't mean you can't get to them. Anything else would make it impossible.